# how to compare headers with httpclient spies in angular

Tags: angular, httpclient, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I need to check if my post request is being called with the same header that I'm setting in the it() test.

What I am doing is:

```
let jwt = 'aaa.bbb.ccc';
let jsonRequest: any = {};
let headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(jwt)})}
```

in my post.subscribe:

```
  expect(httpClientSpy.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(theAppURL + '?verb', jsonRequest, headers);
```

this is giving me an error, obviously because I'm comparing two different objects. How can i compare my headers? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpTestingController;

```
const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(sampleService.sampleMethod);
expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
```

After that, you should use, flush and verify all requests are complete

```
req.flush(mockResponse);
httpTestingController.verify();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i do this with spies?